# It is not possible to log in to keycloak through the UI, under the created user

Tags: keycloak

I have a docker-compose file.

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  keycloakdb:
    container_name: keycloak_db
    image: postgres:14
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRESQL_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRESQL_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRESQL_PASS}
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - .\keycloak_db:/var/lib/postgresql
      - .\init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U keycloak" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - keycloak_network

  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak_blog
    depends_on:
      keycloakdb:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      DB_DATABASE: ${POSTGRESQL_DB}
      DB_USER: ${POSTGRESQL_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRESQL_PASS}
      KEYCLOAK_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      DB_VENDOR: ${DB_VENDOR}
      DB_ADDR: ${DB_ADDR}
      DEBUG_PORT: ${DEBUG_PORT}
      DB_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
      TZ: ${TZ}
      DEBUG: ${DEBUG}
    image: jboss/keycloak:latest
    ports:
      - "28080:8080"
      - "8787:8787" # debug port
    networks:
      - keycloak_network

#  pgadmin:
#    container_name: pgadmin_keycloak_db
#    image: dpage/pgadmin4:5.7
#    environment:
#      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "user@db.com"
#      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "user"
#      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: "False"
#    ports:
#      - "5055:80"
#    restart: unless-stopped
#    networks:
#      - keycloak_network
#    depends_on:
#      - keycloakdb

networks:
  keycloak_network:
    driver: bridge
    name:   keycloak_network
```

in the section describing the keycloak deployment, the data of the user who will be the server administrator is specified.

- env

```yaml
KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=root
DEBUG=true
DEBUG_PORT='*:8787'
DB_VENDOR=postgres
DB_ADDR=keycloak_db
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=keycloak_db
DB_USER=keycloak
DB_PASSWORD=kc
TZ=Europe/Paris
POSTGRESQL_USER=postgres
POSTGRESQL_PASS=postgres
POSTGRESQL_DB=keycloak_db
```

Using this account, I log into keycloak (via UI), create a realm and a new user in it, to whom I assign a password. However, I then cannot log in under the rights of the created user, who would have to manage the realm created earlier.

Does anyone know what the problem might be and how it can be solved ?

Comment: I tried to do this as described here - https://migueldoctor.medium.com/run-keycloak-locally-using-docker-and-secure-your-apps-in-3-steps-f6c554427e54

Comment: can you share environment variable too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your sharing `.env` information. I can run your `docker-compose.yml` file.

If you give a user to all of manage-xxxx roles of realm-management, she can setup/see logging events.

1 Go to users a specific user (my demo user1)
I made realm and client as same as your [linked information](https://migueldoctor.medium.com/run-keycloak-locally-using-docker-and-secure-your-apps-in-3-steps-f6c554427e54)

2 Select `Role Mappings` tab

3 select Client Roles with `realm-management`

4 Selected all of `manage-xxxxx` from `Available Roles`

5 press `Add selected` button

[image]

It will give a power to monitor log event.

#6 logout and login with his `username` and password as admin URI

Example) `my-demo-app` is user's realm

```
http://localhost:28080/auth/admin/my-demo-app/console
```

[image]

#7 Enable login & admin events from `Event Config` tab

[image]

It will shows this screen

[image]

Then she can see all of login/Admin event as this screen

[image]